# How to generalize $f = \frac{u}{v}$, $u,v$ scalars, for vectors?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Suppose $f = \frac{u}{v}$ for some scalars $u,v$. How does one go about generalizing this for vectors $\mathbf{u,v}$? I think there is no concept such as division by a vector ..

Comment: What is *the* generalisation of multiplication?

Answer (score 2):

Though it is not fully clear what type of generalization we are talking about, I can say that a related concept for matrices (which are generalizations of vectors) is the [Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse). For vectors $\mathbf{u,v}$, you can, in fact, define the "vector divisor" operation to be the following: $$\mathbf{w=Div(u,v):=\frac{uv^T}{(v^Tv)}}$$ whenver $\mathbf{u\ne 0}$, though $\mathbf{w}$ is a matrix now, instead of a vector. In a similar way you can define another "division" operation which gives you a scalar instead of a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Not even multiplication is strictly speaking generalizable to vectors. Multiplication in the sense of inner operation on the vector space is open to definition, and cannot always be done. For instance, dot product isn't proper multiplication (result is a scalar and multiplication of 3 vectors is bogus). Cross product is better in this sense.

One answer to your question is simply, that vector spaces don't have the same structure as real and complex fields and you cannot expect each operator to generalize without either breaking internal consistency or violating assumptions about the operation itself.

However, there is something you can do. With the notion of clifford algebras, you can define multiplication through a quadratic form, and then generalize to division as well. The side effect in this generalization is that *scalars and vectors are now parts of the same space, and can be multiplied/divided with each other in any combination*. Or, looking a bit differently, scalars are just special cases of vectors.

Generalization to 2D is obvious: 2D Clifford algebra are complex numbers, which obviously are a 2D vector space. Real numbers act as scalars, and multiplication of two "vectors" multiplies magnitudes and adds polar angles, a well known property of complex numbers in polar coordinates (exponential form). Existence of multiplication in this sense also implies division (can be "rationalized" as $\frac{u}{v}=\frac{u v^\ast}{|v|^2}$) and also vectors (complex numbers) can now be arguments to all analytical functions.

There is no 3D clifford algebra. However, there is one in 4D: the quaternions. In this case, you can imagine combining scalars and 3D vectors into a 4D vector, $(s,\vec{v})$ and multiplication becomes $(s_1,\vec{v}_1)(s_2,\vec{v}_2)=(s_1s_2-\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2, s_1\vec{v}_2+s_2\vec{v}_1+\vec{v}_1\times\vec{v}_2)$. This is no longer commutative.

Among all quaternions, you can consider "pure vectors" with $s=0$, which multiply with scalars ($\vec{v}=0$) as expected, the cross product is the product of two vectors, and division can be defined as in the case of complex numbers, as $\frac{u}{v}=\frac{uv^\ast}{|v|^2}$ where $(s,\vec{v})^\ast=(s,-\vec{v})$.

You can see that the properties you want from multiplication (and division) can only be satisfied in some very limited cases.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can invert a matrix. We often write the inverse of a matrix $A$ as $A^{-1}$. However only square matrices can be inverted. A vector that is not $1 \times 1$ can thus not be inverted.

Writing $f=uv^{-1}$, we see that it is not possible to do this if we use $v^{-1}$ to mean inversion.

---

You could define it. For example: $$\frac{\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{pmatrix}}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1/b_1 \\ a_2/b_2 \\ a_3/b_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

However this does not have the property that it is the inverse of the cross product.

---

Another problem is that multiplication is not really defined for vectors, you have the dot product, but that returns a number rather than a vector. The cross product is defined for vectors with 3 arguments.